# How to execute a Python 3 program in Tkinter with one button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to execute a python 3 file from tkinter when I click a button

**tkinter code**

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as sub

WINDOW_SIZE = "600x400"

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)

tk.Button(root, text="Create Motion!", command=lambda: sub.call('home/pi/motion1.py')).pack()
```

But getting errors when I run the program

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/AnimationGUI.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    tk.Button(root, text="Create Motion!", command=lambda: sub.call('motion1.py')).pack()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 247, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'motion1.py'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, i thought is was the absolute path i had given what i have done wrong?

Comment: perhaps you need a "/" in front of "home/pi/motion1.py"

Comment: thanks for that it solved that part, but now getting [Errno 13] Permission denied ?

Comment: This question is really about how to properly use subprocess.call, not at all about tkinter.  So there should be no tkinter code or tag.  A minimal program with the problem would be `import subprocess; subprocess.call('motion.py')`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all wrong. The proper way to do this is to make "motion1.py" with a function in it that does something. Let's say you call that function "main" (very common). Then your code would be:

```
import tkinter as tk
import motion1

WINDOW_SIZE = "600x400"

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Create Motion!", command=motion1.main)
btn.pack()
```

Assuming that your code and "motion1.py" are in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks for the above code however, it does not draw the window to press the button, it calls the motion1.py and launches the camera?

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE BELOW                                                                       btn = tk.Button(root, text="Create Motion!", command = motion1.main)
AttributeError: module 'motion1' has no attribute 'main

Comment: @Coyney22 You need to put all the code into a function named "main" first.

Comment: thanks for this can you give me an example of a function with the code above, I learn through doing, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec()` in a function as you call the button's command.

You should avoid using lambda and just use a regular function.

Also, to make sure the file gets closed, just wrap a `with` block around `exec()`

```
from tkinter import * 
window = Tk()
window.geometry("100x100")
window.title('Run another program')

def runsomething():
    with open("yourpathhere.py") as file:
       exec(open("thesamepathhere.py").read()) # exec() in python 3 is the equivalent of execfile() in python 2 #


btn = Button(window, text = "Run a program", command=runsomething)
btn.pack()


window.mainloop()
```